# Modify uk biometric-residence-permit (BRP) after change in course duration (from less than 12 months to over 12 months)

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I am currently on a UK Tier-4 Student visa pursuing master's degree. When my CAS (Confirmation of Acceptance of Studies) was issued, the course duration was over 6 months but less than 12 months. So, I was issued visa for 2 months extra time after the end of the course. Now, the university has changed the course end date and the course duration has become over 12 months. Now my course end date is the same as the expiry date of my visa. Also, as now my course is over 12 months, I should be entitled to 4 months extra time after my course end. However, it is not reflected in my current biometric residence permit (BRP).

Is it possible to flag this as a mistake in the duration of BRP, and get a replacement BRP with the extended expiry date?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to [apply to extend your Tier 4 (General) student visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/extend-your-visa). Your visa validity more than covered the program duration, as documented by the university in the original CAS.

The subsequent prolongation was done by the university, as you describe it. For purposes of the visa extension application, you should request an amended CAS from the university, as it remains responsible for you until you leave the UK.

Unless you have submitted a visa application to extend your permission in the UK, you would have to leave by the expiry date on your visa.